# javascript file not found in node express handlebars app

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, handlebars.js

My app is not loading .js file, css file, or image from my public folder.
These are the errors that I'm getting in the console:

1. GET http://localhost:8080/assets/images/burger.jpg 404 (Not Found)
2. GET http://localhost:8080/burgers.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
3. Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/assets/css/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Here are my paths in the head of main.handlebars:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/style.css" type="text/css">
<script src="/assets/js/burgers.js"></script>
```

I've included this in my middleware in server.js:

```js
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

And here is my directory:

- public

  - assets

    - css

      - style.css
    - js

      - burgers.js
    - images

      - burger.jpg
- views

  - layouts

    - main.handlebars
  - index.handlebars
- server.js

Comment: Is it not because your `app.use(express.static('public'));` path is wrong? Maybe try `app.use(express.static('/public'));`

Comment: @DaneBrouwer That didn't work either, ugh. 
Also of note, my teacher cloned my repository to help debug it and none of the public folders/files exist for her, even though they exist in my repository. Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: @DaneBrouwer I've also tried
`app.set(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

Comment: Let's continue this chat [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209501/chat)

Comment: @DaneBrouwer apparently I don't have enough points to chat, I just made an account today for this issue. But here is a link to the repository https://github.com/sarahm16/burger

Comment: Posted an issue on your repository we can chat there.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" type="text/css">
<script src="assets/js/burgers.js"></script>
```

Or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css" type="text/css">
<script src="./assets/js/burgers.js"></script>
```

Comment: The /js before burgers is missing

Comment: Thank you for the response! But even with the js, neither of those work

Comment: If your server.js file is not on the same level as the public folder, you need to specify to full path 

`express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))`

Comment: I edited the post to show where server.js file is, it looks to me like it's on the same level as the public folder. I have also tried `app.set(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` with no success

Comment: Yea. I cloned your repo. Not sure why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I used terminal to create my directory and apparently I named my folders 'public ' and ' assets' with spaces in the folder names that I couldn't see. Renamed them and everything is working properly now. Thank you everyone!